# Sum the result of every 2 rows, if the result is negative

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a single column of numbers, I need to sum row 1 and row 2, sum row 3 and row 4, all the way to the end of column. And then, I need to sum all the previous result if the result is negative only. 
I can only do this series of adding without creating more columns because I have to to this for many columns and I don't want to create another column to store the sub result as that will double the number of columns.

Any way I can achieve this with excel formula? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(OFFSET($A$1,(ROW(A1)-1)*2+1,0,2))),"")
```

[image]

Edit #.1

In `A10`, enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+TEXT((A2:A8*MOD(ROW(A2:A8)-1,2))+(A3:A9*MOD(ROW(A2:A8)-1,2)),"\0;-0"))
```

[image]

Comment: hi, hmm, actually, your formula works if I have a Col B. However, I must remove column B, I need a formula to sum all the negative subresult in A10. Col B is just for showing the sub step.

Answer (score 0):

another SUMPRODUCT version:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--TEXT(ISEVEN(ROW(A2:A8))*(A2:A8+A3:A9),"\0;-0;0"))
```

[image]